# Is there a way in docusign NodeJS to authenticate using X-DocuSign-Authentication

Tags: docusignapi

This is something that worked very well in our PHP environment and looks like something like this

```
 $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . config('docusign.email') . "\",\"Password\":\"" . config('docusign.password') . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . config('docusign.integrator_key') . "\"}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is "legacy" authentication. It is not supported for new integrations. Plus it is not as secure as oauth, and does not support SSO, or 2FA.

Oauth works well and we will assist you if you have problems with it.

Comment: Larry thank you, I need to create an accessToken for my application that does not expire and I believe all the jwt tokens from the documentation expire.

Comment: Yes, but your app can create a new access token via jwt grant anytime it needs one

Comment: Do you create a separate one for the development environment and production?

Comment: Yes, you can freely generate JWT auth tokens in both demo and production, but a token generated in Demo won't work in Prod.